# Website compiled in 64bit not connecting to sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7.5

I have a strange problem.

I have web application that use both `Oracle` and `sql server 2008`.

I want to use the Oracle Data Provider for `.NET 64bit` version.
in order to that i am setting the application pool to enable 32 bit = false, otherwise the ODT.NET 64bit is not working.
So also i had to compile the assemblies to be 64bit.
but when i do so i'm getting the following error from sql server:

```
 A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection
 to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance 
 name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
```

when i compile back to any cpu it's working fine, but again  only if i set the application pool to enable 32bit=true.

what make things even more strange is that in my test and pre prod servers it's working fine with 64bit setup both for sql server and oracle.

but in my prod server i keep getting this error from sql.

so maybe it's IIS problem in my prod machine?

what  i did so far is to compare all the settings in the iis to be the same in all machines, but it didn't solve the problem.

what could it be?

Comment: What you describe is very strange but the error you are getting doesn't seem related to the fact that the assemblies are compiled for a 64 bit architecture. It looks more a configuration issue; a networking problem.

Comment: Have you checked your connection string??

Comment: I thought the Oracle drivers would only work on a 32bit application pool. Hmmm

Comment: yes i have checked to connection string

Comment: also make sure the server is up and running

Answer (score -1):

The problem solved!

it turned out that in that specific machine i need to call the sql server in the connection string by name and not by ip.

Comment: So how on earth did this relate to 32-bit vs. 64-bit? I thought you said you checked the connection string?